# How to Block Call in Android Nougat, Oreo and above programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-phone-call, callblocking

This code works fine till **Android 6** (**Marshmallow**):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm); 
c = Class.forName(telephonyService.getClass().getName()); 
m = c.getDeclaredMethod("endCall"); 
m.setAccessible(true); 
m.invoke(telephonyService);
```

[After reading documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#endCall())

I called `endCall(context, number)` still, Unable to block call. Need working solution in Android Nougat, Oreo, Pie and above.

**Update**

I included following code from official Nougat documentation but still, the number was not added into blocklist.

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ID,
                            BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER,
                            BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_E164_NUMBER}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @jackjay The link you provided is broken, I believe you meant [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/block-numbers).

Comment: This is corrected link: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/block-numbers I'm implementing it now.

Comment: yes you should follow this link.

Comment: I only wanted to put numbers in blacklist hence, I wrote this:

` ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER, "1234567890");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI, values); `

But that's not putting the numbers into blocklist

Answer (score 0):

Android 9 can not use non-SDK interfaces

> Android 9 introduces new restrictions on the use of non-SDK
>   interfaces, whether directly, via reflection, or via JNI. These
>   restrictions are applied whenever an app references a non-SDK
>   interface or attempts to obtain its handle using reflection or JNI.

And it looks like you can not read or write to `BlockedNumberContract` unless it's a system app or default dialer or default sms app

> Permissions
>
> Only the system, the default SMS application, and the default phone
>   app (See TelecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage()), and carrier apps
>   (See CarrierService) can read, and write to the blockednumber
>   provider. However, canCurrentUserBlockNumbers(Context) can be accessed
>   by any application.